# Spring Data JPA detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have two entities User and **ContactDetail**. One user can have many **ContactDetails**.

There is also a **UserService** component which is responsible for persisting new Users. It checks if the ContactDetail exists and if so attaches that entity to new User entity and then attempts to save it.

User.java

```
 public class User extends Base implements Resource<UUID>, UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<ContactDetail> contactdetails;

    @Transient
    public String email; 

    //bidirectional consistency 
    public void addContactDetail(ContactDetail contactDetail){
    if(this.contactdetails == null){
        this.contactdetails = new ArrayList<ContactDetail>();
    }
    if(!this.getContactDetails().contains(contactDetail)){
        this.getContactDetails().add(contactDetail);
        contactDetail.addUser(this);
    }
}
```

ContactDetail.java

```
public class ContactDetail extends Base implements Resource<UUID> {

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ContactType type;

@Column(name = "value", unique = true)
private String value;

@Column(name = "verified")
private boolean isVerified;

@Column(name = "created_date")
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "expired")
boolean isExpired;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
protected User user; 

 //bidirectional consistency 
 public void addUser(User user) {
    if (this.getUser() == null) {
        this.setUser(user);
        user.addContactDetail(this);
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserService extends AbstractRestResource<User, UUID,     User.UserWrapper> {


@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
protected User save(User e) {
    attachedContact(e);

    User savedUser = repository().save(e);
    return savedUser;
}

private void attachedContact(User u) {
    ContactDetail contactDetail = contactDetailsRepository.findByTypeAndValue(ContactType.PRIMARY_EMAIL, u.getEmail());
    if (contactDetail == null) {
        contactDetail = new ContactDetail(u.getFirstName(), ContactType.PRIMARY_EMAIL, u.getEmail());
    }
    u.addContactDetail(contactDetail);
}
```

If ContactDetail entity DOES NOT exist then Both User and ContactDetail entities are saved as expected.

If ContactDetail entity DOES exist I received the following error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.test.ContactDetail
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
```

Comment: Looks like your transaction is broken, this happens when you load in one transaction, change and save in another. Verify that save(User) is running in transaction  with TransactionSynchronizationManager

Comment: Hey Nadir you're right. TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() returns false instead of true. The annotation on top of the save(user) method: @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW) is not starting a transaction. How do I fix this ? thanks

Comment: This depends on the way you set up you transactions. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html (in your case I guess it will be @EnableTransactionManagement)

Comment: Thanks Nadir issue was UserService is actually a Controller. Declarative transaction require a service class to start transactions. So I created A user Service class injected it into my Controller and it worked.